# Using NAudio, ADTS AAC to WAV Transcoding, how to?

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, transcoding

I am attempting to implement the following code which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486747/convert-aac-to-wav)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Media;
using NAudio.Wave;


namespace AAC2WAV
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // create media foundation reader to read the AAC encoded file
            using (MediaFoundationReader reader = new MediaFoundationReader(args[0]))
            // resample the file to PCM with same sample rate, channels and bits per sample
            using (ResamplerDmoStream resampledReader = new ResamplerDmoStream(reader,
                new WaveFormat(reader.WaveFormat.SampleRate, reader.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample, reader.WaveFormat.Channels)))
            // create WAVe file
            using (WaveFileWriter waveWriter = new WaveFileWriter(args[1], resampledReader.WaveFormat))
            {
                // copy samples
                resampledReader.CopyTo(waveWriter);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Input file is *.aac (args[0]) output file should be *.wav (args[ 1 ]).
I am running the complied code as a console application and I get no errors, however it just seems to hang once it creates the wav file with 0 KB size

I'm wondering is there there is something I am missing or perhaps something I need to further understand.

Windows is reporting the *.aac files as ADTS.

Perhaps it is that I need to extract and rewrite the header, but I am not familiar with AAC at all so would seek some guidance on that aspect if deemed necessary.

When I try to open the file with WMP it says it cannot connect to the server *(suggests codec issue)*, however I can convert it with FFMPEG to a wav file without any trouble. Using FFMPEG is not ideal for the particular implementation I am looking at.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Info on the actual file:**

```
General 
Complete name : C:\Users\....\AAC2WAV\bin\Debug\0cc409aa-f66c-457a-ac10-6286509ec409.aac 
Format : ADIF 
Format/Info : Audio Data Interchange Format 
File size : 180 KiB 
Overall bit rate mode : Constant 

Audio 
Format : AAC 
Format/Info : Advanced Audio Codec 
Format profile : Main 
Bit rate mode : Constant 
Channel(s) : 14 channels 
Channel positions : , Back: 14 
Sampling rate : 96.0 kHz 
Frame rate : 93.750 FPS (1024 spf) 
Compression mode : Lossy 
Stream size : 180 KiB (100%)
```

Information gathered from file using: [MediaInfo](http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo)

I should add here that the lower section of the above info is incorrect I believe.
The sample rate is not 96k it is 22050 and there is only 1 channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the resampler - `MediaFoundationReader` already returns PCM. You should also use `WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile`

This should be all you need:

```
using (var reader = new MediaFoundationReader("myfile.aac"))
{
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile("pcm.wav", reader);
}
```

Comment: Mark, Interesting that the returned wav file data starts at byte position 46 rather than 44. I see this is due to the subchunk size being 18 rather than 16. Can you elaborate on why this is the case and where the extra 2 bytes are used please?

Comment: it's the difference between WAVEFORMAT and WAVEFORMATEX

Comment: OK, thanks, so we are omitting the cbSize and extra data in WAVEFORMAT as opposed to in [WAVEFORMATEX](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=WAVEFORMATEX) where those values are present. I have seen a number of different header lengths recently, in particular from the output of FFMPEG (aac > wav) where I noticed an offset of 76 bytes due to metadata as well. Makes sense now. Cheers mate.